# How to do math with GUIDs in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to do some math with SQL Server GUIDs in a trigger and I'm having difficulty figuring out how to convert a `uniqueidentifier` to a `numeric(38,0)`.

One potential problem: my understand is that both of these datatypes are 16-byte "integers". If I'm wrong here, please correct me.

Otherwise, how would I go about this conversion? I've tried CAST and CONVERT and keep getting **Explicit conversion from data type uniqueidentifier to numeric is not allowed.** as an error message whenever I try. I'd really like to not have to parse each character and do hex math in a UDF to do this.

Is this possible?

Here's my script to repro this real quick:

```
DECLARE @guid uniqueidentifier
SET @guid = NEWID()
DECLARE @a numeric(38,0)
SET @a = 2
PRINT CAST(@guid AS numeric(38,0)) -- fails
PRINT @guid / @a -- also fails
```

Comment: The answer to the inevitable "why" question is we missed a requirement (as in were never told it) but can salvage things with a temporary solution until we can go back in and fix things on our next release.

Comment: `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` is not an 16-byte `INT`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx

Comment: @Lamak As best as I can tell, a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` is a 32-char hex number (max value calculated by 16^32). A 16-byte unsigned integer would be have a max value calculated by 2^(16*8). Just so happens that 2^(16*8) == 2^128 == 16^32. So the two data types can store the same number of values. I'm just trying to convert from one to the other. This is why I have "Integers" in quotes in my original question. I never said anything about an `INT` data type, just a `numeric(38,0)` data type.

Comment: Fair enough, but from the docs it certainly doesn't look like SQL Server provides a numeric conversion for its `uniqueidentifier` type.

Comment: @Jaxidian I thought that you were actually referring to integers. Anyway, the fact that those datatypes can store the same number of values, doesn't mean that you can cast one to the other just like that. You still can't cast 'A' or any other char to integer either.

Comment: @Lamak I would expect some sort of hex conversions to happen in this casting. So if we had a `uniqueidentifier` of "0000000000000A" (I omitted zeroes), the resulting `numeric(38,0)` value would be 10. I'm hoping @DanJ is incorrect but I am unable to conclude that SQL Server doesn't provide a `numeric` conversion for `uniqueidentifier`. I'm not sure what documentation would say that such a thing doesn't exist.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a 16 byte integer either. `SELECT CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(16)) AS NUMERIC(38,0))` gives `Arithmetic overflow error converting varbinary to data type numeric.` or `Error converting data type varbinary to numeric.`

Comment: @Jaxidian You can't directly cast `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` to a numeric data type. You can first cast it to `VARBINARY`, then a numeric datat type, but I don't know if what you get as a result is consistent with some mathematic calculation. `SELECT CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS BIGINT)`

Comment: @Lamak - `BIGINT` is only 8 bytes so that would just do half the data.

Comment: @MartinSmith I know, it was only to explain that you could convert it to a numeric data type (though I'm not sure about how it does it)

Comment: @lamak That `varbinary` solution seems to work in concept. Having some issues but please post that as an Answer. I think that's the piece I'm missing. :-)

Comment: @Jaxidian Sorry, I can't post that as an answer since I'm not certain that the results are consistent nor am I clear about the rules it's using for this particular conversion. I'd rather not post a possible wrong answer.

Comment: @Lamak Your answer isn't a complete answer but it gave me what I need. Using that, I can take a GUID in 4 parts, convert them to bigints, do what I need, and use math to fix everything up in the end. It's easy to convert from bigints to numeric. I'll post my final solution and give you credit but if you want the checkmark for the answer, it's yours since you keyed me into the missing piece I needed (i.e. converting to varbinary).

Comment: @Jaxidian Thanks for your comment, but I think that its better that you post your complete solution to your problem, and then mark it as accepted than me posting an incomplete answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I haven't stumbled on a conversion from a hexadecimal value in a `VARCHAR` to a `NUMERIC` short of looping through one digit at a time.

```
declare @GUID as UniqueIdentifier = NewId()
declare @Binary as VarBinary(64) = @GUID
declare @String as VarChar(64) = Convert( VarChar(64), @Binary, 2 )

select @GUID as 'GUID', @Binary as 'Binary', @String as 'String'
```